# Backbone - Mocha - setElement unbinding events for tests

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, marionette, sinon

When writing tests for `Backbone`/`Marionette` `Views` I have noticed that at times, when using `setElement` in the `render` or `onRender` (if a `marionette itemView`), I cannot later trigger a specific event (i.e `click`) on an element set in the view's `events` hash, from my tests.
However when doing `element.dispatchEvent('createdEvent')` in the test suit, no error is reported, but the method I am spying on with `sinon` is never called.

If I simply stub the `setElement` method it returns an error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.$el.attr')`.

I am guessing I need some more setting-up to do in my tests apart from simply instantiating the `view and necessary`models`and`collections`along with any`spies`,`stubs`, or`fakeServers`, or either refactoring the existing`views`and removing the`setElement` method?

Has anyone come across a similar situation before?

How do I get around this?

I am using `mocha`, `chai`, `sinon` and `phantomjs` for my tests.

I have a more detailed SO question, with a working example, on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828501/marionette-itemview-click-event-not-firing-when-triggered-from-tests